# tried to change plugin to use MySQL in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

MariaDB [(none)]> USE mysql;

Reading table information for completion of table and column names

You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed

MariaDB [mysql]> UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';

ERROR 1356 (HY000): View 'mysql.user' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them

Answer (score 1):

Please do not try to change system tables that could result in an unusable system. For exact that reason mysql.user table was changed to a read only view years ago.

Changing authentication plugin, password etc. should be done via [ALTER USER](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-user/) SQL command.